# Opengl GLES20.glViewport() change shape to circle

Tags: java, opengl-es, webrtc

I am aware that according to the GLES20 documentation, `glViewport(int x, int y, int width, int height)` creates a rectangular viewport.

Is there perhaps a way to use a different polygon (or circular) shaped viewport instead?

I'd like to display a stream from webrtc inside a viewport. The current issue is that the viewport in which it is displayed is rectangular and therefore it shows a black background behind the stream (See image linked)

This code is adapted from react-native-webrtc.

`private static final FloatBuffer FULL_RECTANGLE_BUF = GlUtil.createFloatBuffer(new float[] {-0.5f, -1.0f, 0.5f, -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f,-0.5f,  1.0f,0.5f,  1.0f,});`

`GLES20.glViewport(x, y, width, height);`

`GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6);`

[Image of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1heH.jpg)

Comment: Please describe what using a circular viewport would mean to you? Circle in a black rectangle inside a window? Circle, otherwise fully transparent, i.e. visible desktop? Paint a picture with words...

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch Thanks for the response. I have updated the question. Hopefully this paints a better picture of the problem and the output I'm looking for

Comment: I recommend to visualise the desired result (ASCII art or another picture). I guess that it is important to define what you want to see in the area which is not inside the desired circular view port but is inside the unwanted rectangular viewport.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is your final scene constructed? Is this two viewports inside a single render pass?